# Object 'X' already exists

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm learning C++ and am redoing a tutorial that I did before. I deleted the project folder and recreated it. I right clicked on the solution, clicked Add Class and entered my class name, but I get the error that 'Object 'X' already exists' even though I deleted the previous folder. I'm just learning C++ so I guess I don't understand how C++ creates objects.

Comment: It sounds like it is not a C++ object, but a visual studio object.  You may be able to hunt down a way to delete whatever is making visual studio think the class still exists, but if that proves frustrating and this is just a small project with one or two files, it may be easier to just make a new project and copy your code into new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably some stored data are still there from the previous project.
1st solution: I would suggest you to change from the name tag, your project name. Maybe something was still there.
Then, second option: restart Visual studio

2nd solution: Watch also to the solution explorer, if there are hidden folder named as your class name. If so, delete them and create the class again

Let me know.

Comment: Thanks this was strange. My Recent Documents had a reference to the class and even though the class was deleted it was still causing the issue. I deleted the reference from my recent documents and it worked. Don't understand why but this was all I did.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I created a file with the name that did not work via windows explorer in my project folder. I then dragged the file into visual studio and it worked.